# How to replace previous value with new calculated value

Tags: c, loops, iteration

I'm doing a C program to solve a system of linear equations by using a fixed-point iteration method, and the problem is that it works non-stop and gives all same numbers in each iteration. I guess the problem is with replacing new values of x with previous (I know I have to change the titles of x in iterations, but that's not the main problem).
And the reason why user inputs the size and the program calculates only for 3, because earlier I did cases for sizes 2-5, but noticed some mistakes so I decided to stay with 3 for now to understand how actually it should work.

Maybe someone can tell how can I fix that?

**The result of the program:**

```
     Enter the size of system:3

     Enter the acceptable error:0.001

    Enter coefficients(written in matrix form).
     For example,
    1       2       3
    2       6       8

    5 -1 3
    1 -4 2
    2 -1 5

    Enter constants.
    For example, 1        2       3       2       6

    5 20 10

    Results of 0th approximation:
    x0 = 1.000000
    x1 = -5.000000
    x2 = 2.000000
    Results of 1-th approximation:
    x1 = -1.200000
    x1 = -3.750000
    x1 = -0.200000
    Results of 2-th approximation:
    x2 = -1.200000
    x2 = -3.750000
    x2 = -0.200000
    Results of 3-th approximation:
    x3 = -1.200000
    x3 = -3.750000
    x3 = -0.200000
    Results of 4-th approximation:
    x4 = -1.200000
    x4 = -3.750000
    x4 = -0.200000
    Results of 5-th approximation:
    x5 = -1.200000
    x5 = -3.750000
    x5 = -0.200000
    Results of 6-th approximation:
    x6 = -1.200000
    x6 = -3.750000
    x6 = -0.200000
    Results of 7-th approximation:
    x7 = -1.200000
    x7 = -3.750000
    x7 = -0.200000
```

(And it works non-stop)

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#define MS 5 //max size of system

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");
    int size, numb, m = 1; //actual size of system, number of iterations, marker of stopping

    float d, e[MS]; //array of measurement errors
    float k[MS][MS];//coefficients before x
    float vch[MS]; //array of constants
    float prev[MS]; //previous values of х
    float nev[MS]; //new values of х

    printf("\n\t Enter the size of system:");
    scanf_s("%d", &size);
    if (size < 2 || size>5)
    {
        printf("The size does not fit");
    }

    printf("\n\t Enter the acceptable error:");
    scanf_s("%f", &d);
    int i, j;
    printf("\n\tEnter coefficients(written in matrix form).\n\t For example,\n\t1\t2\t3\n\t2\t6\t8\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            scanf_s("%f", &k[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n\tEnter constants.\n For example, 1\t2\t3\t2\t6\n\n");
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            scanf_s("%f", &vch[j]);
        }

        //calculate the 0th approximation
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            prev[i] = vch[i] / k[i][i];
        }
        //print results
        printf("\n\tResults of 0th approximation:\t");
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            printf("\n\tx%d = %f\t", i, prev[i]);
        }
            for (numb = 1; m != 0; numb++)
            {
                nev[0] = ((vch[0] - k[0][1] * prev[1] - k[0][2] * prev[2]) / k[0][0]);
                nev[1] = ((vch[1] - k[1][0] * prev[0] - k[1][2] * prev[2]) / k[1][1]);
                nev[2] = ((vch[2] - k[0][1] * prev[1] - k[0][2] * prev[2]) / k[0][0]);

                for (i = 0; i < size; i++)//loop of calculating errors
                {
                    e[i] = fabs(nev[i] - prev[i]) / fabs(nev[i]);
                }
                printf("\n\Results of %d-th approximation:\t", numb);
                for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
                {   
                    printf("\n\tx%d = %f\t",numb , nev[i]);
                    printf("\n");
                }
                for (i = 0; i < size; i++) //loop of changing values
                {
                    nev[i] = prev[i];
                }                   
                if (e[0] <= d || e[1] <= d || e[2] <= d)
                {
                    m = 0;
                }
            }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems you want to calculate new values `nev[i]` from previous values `prev[i]`. This means in the next round of your loop, `prev` must hold what was in `nev` before. You assign `nev[i] = prev[i];` Try the other direction.

Comment: Try to debug your code. It's hard to read and I don't know the method you're using.

Comment: nev[i] = prev[i] should be  prev[i] = nev[i]